# Can Oauth2 Access Token be shared by client?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am new to OAUTH and trying out understanding the spec. So as per the [spec protocol flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2), I understand that Client A, can get Authorization code and then Access Token for a protected resource.

Now if Access Token has been obtained, Services e.g Linked in expects the Access token to be part of URL Query, [See their interface document](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

So now if Client A has shared access token with Client B, or e.g anyone intercepts the request, and gets the access token, then he too can start accessing all details that Client A can access. Is this understanding correct? If yes, then how can we protect such kind of Access token sharing/misuse?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to pass an access token to endpoints of protected resources. For example, as a query parameter like:

> `access_token={Your-Access-Token}`

Another example is Bearer Token Usage ([RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)) in which an access token is embedded in Authorization header like:

> `Authorization: Bearer {Your-Access-Token}`

How to pass an access token is defined by each service.

Access tokens must be kept secret. If Client B obtains an access token issued to Client A, Client B can behave as if it were Client A. Yes, there are risks of access token leakage, so access tokens have limited lifetime, and it is a reason that most services have a page to enable users to revoke access tokens.