# How Jwt token really works in a login system?

Tags: php, session, authentication, jwt, token

I am struggle for a stable answer for this question and not getting any. My doubts are

1. do we need to store the user name and password in the token and if yes then how that i.e where this data are getting store in the payload part is it in the `sub`?
2. do we need to store the token in the DB while registering
3. Does Jwt token are unique for same set of data ( I think no cause of the different time)
4. how to verify user? that is first creating a token of the data from the inputs then 
   creating token  and verifying it with the token in the DB?
5. How to logout?
6. Is it better than session

Comment: I hate people closing/downvoting things like that.

Comment: It's off topic as this site is for specific code questions, not "Explain this thing to me."

Comment: @Jeff Sure.  But this is a useful question and could result in a useful discussion with useful specific-enough answers.  I understand the desire to have rules but I don't agree that it is always beneficial.

Comment: Fair enough. It may be a better question for the Software Engineering SE then, but I digress.

Comment: I never heard about the idea to store the password in the token before, but today it's the second time this comes up. Strange.

Comment: @jps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases#Frequency_illusion

Comment: @MK.damn phsycology ,-)  but honestly, never heard that password thing

Comment: @MK did you ever hear that?

Comment: I am too old to be surprised by the way people chose to get security wrong.

Comment: Clearly, this question did not deserved to be closed, These all doubts are something which I was carrying in my head since last few days. The question and the answer were quite helpful. I don't know why some Gurus think that the question was too broad/can be made granular/or can be moved to some other SE site. Please **Gurus** , the main agenda is to learn things rather than applying utterly nonsense traffic rules over here. I completely agree with @MK. Voting to reopen it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You need to store some user identification in JWT.  Usually it makes sense to list her granted rights verified during authentication and something like display name.  Definitely do not store password.

2) No, token is not stored in the database.  Tokens are short lived and need to be re-issued every few minutes transparently to user.

3) Every time JWT is re-issued it is unique because one of the things encoded in it is the timestamp for when it expires.

4) First token is created during authentication.  Then each request validates the token by decoding it using the private key you used to encode it.  If the token is expiring soon you issue the new one using the same data + updated expiration timestamp.

5) Log out is now a front end's job.  You need to stop sending requests with the token.  Perhaps delete the cookie if you are sending JWT as a cookie.

6) This is better than using session because it is stateless.  First obvious win is that you no longer need to store session info in database/maintain client ip address affinity if you are running a cluster of multiple web servers.

Comment: When you say list her granted rights, does this mean that what operations that user is allowed to perform/ or API methods allowed to call based on their role? And also, how to validate the token and extract information from the token itself, that from which user is it has come. I am specifically confused about the validation of token.

Comment: Storing rights is just a shortcut so that you don't need to perform database lookup on every API call.  When you authenticate user you figure out her role, or list of rights, or whatever - up to you.  And then just keep that in the token so that a specific call can just authorize based on that.  Token is (timestamp, username, rights, signature).  Signature is derived from the first 3 fields + private key.  Only an entity which has the private key can generate the correct signature.  That's how your backend methods know that requestor is who she claims she is.

Comment: Thanks, That is helpful...

Comment: [But this case is clinging in my mind now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23798963/681929), a developer can create an app and after getting the oauth token , can share it across multiple platforms or apps. Though this all seems to me that I am thinking too much of it, and the token will get invalidated after sometime according to the expiration date time set by me, but this seems to me a valid use case

Comment: Any go in this one @MK?

Comment: JWT is oauth are different things.  You can't share jwt across platform and apps.  It is for authenticating to a particular service/app.   The token should obviously be sent over https.  Tokens are usually only valid for a couple of minutes, backend has to reissue them (you'll need to make sure there is some heartbeat call to backend more frequently than token expiration).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to MKs answer (to which I agree) and specifically to your questions 1 and 4:
The password is only used in the first request to obtain the accesss token and of course never part of the token itself.

When you request the access token for the first time, you usually start by sending a token request to the token endpoint, in case of the so called [`Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant`](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant) with user credentials in the request header, e.g.

```
grant_type=password&username=user1&passowrd=very_secret
```

The authorization server (which might be a different endpoint on your resource server) will check the credentials and create an access token which will be used on all subsequent calls to the resource server. The resource server just checks the validity of the token, i.e checks if the signature matches the content.

For reference : JWT is described in [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)

General introduction can be found on https://jwt.io

Comment: Your example looks like putting password into the GET request url parameter which is not a good idea as it might leak into web server logs and browser history.

Comment: No, that's a request header, not a url parameter

Comment: See [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/) for example